# How to extract inline-tag styles from an html?

Tags: javascript

I have an html page with some `<style>/*I need to extract this*/</style>`
and how can I extract that styles and get html without styles?

Comment: So you want to remove all the style in `style` tag?

Comment: yes, and save them in a string variable

Comment: Please add more details. Do you want to extract the styles at build time or run time (in the browser)? Also, could you please include an example with "before" and "after", including all files involved?

Comment: Curious if my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you you use [all:initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) or `all:unset` so that you could make the element use default style.

I don't think you could create variable for the class, but you could use `classList.add` and `classList.remove` to switch.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick= function(){
document.body.classList.add("nostyle");
this.classList.add('nostyle');

}
```

```css
.nostyle{
all:revert;
}
body{
background:black;

}
button{
color:white;
background:black;
}
```

```html
<button >Remove</button>
```